# Recyclers item duplicating item on screen rotate or screen lock

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, mvvm, android-recyclerview, pagination

I'm trying to use Firestore with MVVM and pagination for my project by following [Alex Mamo's example](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tVwl8D5rWcw) ([Repository with the example from the video](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreRealtimePagination)).

Whenever device is rotated, the items in the list are being deleted and on device screen lock, the items in the `Recycler` item are being duplicated.

I'm looking for a workaround or a solution to this issue in Java.

Comment: Hi @Kabirubashiru, welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your description and mention what exactly you tried before facing the item duplication. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.